# Is there a way to use Kubernetes LeaderElection across multiple clusters?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, leader-election

We are using the native Kubernetes LeaderElection, but it appears to only work within the cluster. Is there a way to make this work across multiple clusters?

Official Client: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/src/KubernetesClient/LeaderElection

```cs
/* EXAMPLE CODE */
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

    var kubeCfg = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildDefaultConfig();
    var client = new Kubernetes(kubeCfg);
    var leaderLock = new LeaseLock(client, kubeCfg.Namespace, "leader-lock", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME"));

    var config = new LeaderElectionConfig(leaderLock)
    {
        LeaseDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        RenewDeadline = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        RetryPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
    };
    _leaderElector = new LeaderElector(config);
    _leaderElector.OnStartedLeading += () => _logger.LogInformation("Got Leader Lock");
    _leaderElector.OnNewLeader += leader => _logger.LogInformation("Leader changed to: {leader}", leader);
    _leaderElector.OnStoppedLeading += () => _logger.LogInformation("Lost Leader Lock");

    _leaderElectorTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await _leaderElector.RunAsync(_cts.Token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), _cts.Token);
            }
        }
    });
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: hi @Don Rhummy, sorry I don't have answer to your question but I'm interested in using KubernetesClient in C# for active/standby implementation. Do you mind explaining how you made your C# code works in a pod running in Kubenertes ? Do you need to assign the Pod a ServiceAccount that binds Roles allowing the specific API access for example ? Or anything else that you need to configure in your kube?